# VBA: For Each loop in a filtered list and ADD text to each cell

Tags: excel, vba, loops, filter, foreach

I managed to modify only the cells in a filtered list using rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), but when i run the code, it takes all the text in all the cells (in the range of the filtered list) and then proceeds to ADD these to each cell. I just want to add a single frase to each cell, not take all the text from all cells and ADD to all the cells. Here is the code:

```
For Each cl In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = ActiveCell.Value & " - [Text here " & myVariable & "]"
       
    Next cl
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```vb
For Each cl In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    cl.Value = cl.Value & " - [Text here " & myVariable & "]"
Next cl
```